# Problem with Rewriting URL [htaccess file]

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

For Removing Trailing Slash, Removing ".php" and for Redirecting with ".php" Request to Removed Version, I Collected Some Codes from the Internet. Then I Tried to Add A Rule That will Rewrite files from "proto" Folder to URL Without "/proto/".

e.g. - "http://example.com/proto/filename.php" to "http://example.com/filename(.php)"

But Actually, It Did not Work. Here the Entire Code

```
# Was Requested By Host
php_value display_errors 1

# Some Spooky Scary Settings
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Proto-File Requested Case
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /proto/$1 [NC,L]

# Slash-Trail Requested Case
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [NC,L,R=301]

# .PHP Requested Case
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [NC,L,R=301]

# Without .PHP Requested Case
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [NC,L]

# Error Pages
ErrorDocument 500 /modules/errors/500.php
ErrorDocument 404 /modules/errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /modules/errors/403.php
```

Can Someone Help Me to Edit This And Say What is the Problem ??

Answer (score 0):

Try the following before your existing rules:

```
RewriteRule ^proto/(.*) /$1 [R=302,L]
```

This should redirect* `/prono/filename` to `/filename`.

Change the 302 (temporary) redirect to 301 (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK

Comment: well yeah it worked, but I wanted that "/filename" loaded content of "/proto/filename"

Comment: Mate, I tested right that edited version, yeah it's working (it's actually redirecting), but I wanted "/filename" request to load the "/proto/filename.php" as its own.